# d2: get full count of units in core.time.Duration

Tags: d

I'm messing with `core.time.Duration`s - in particular, I'm trying to properly get number of full minutes in "2 days and 1 hour" `Duration`. As it have cleared, `get!"minutes"` returns number of minutes **without** hours, days and weeks (e.g. 0 in this case), so it's inappropriate for me, because I expect answer of 2940.

I've looked into sources and found `core.time.getUnitsFromHNSecs` function, which does exactly what I need, but it's private to `core.time` and uses private field `_hnsecs` of `Duration` objects.

Of course, it's possible to do

```
long minutes_in_duration(Duration d) {
    return (d.get!"minutes"() + d.get!"hours"() * 60 + 
            d.get!"days"() * 24 * 60 + d.get!("weeks") * 7 * 24 * 60);
}
```

but this is clumsy as hell. Is there better way to do the same thing without scattering away `Duration`'s guts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More thorough reading through source revealed overlooked `.total!"unit"` property, which does exactly what it should.

Comment: Yes. Both `get` and `total` are explained in the documentation: http://dlang.org/phobos/core_time.html

Comment: Also, as you've found your answer, please mark it as your chosen answer so that the question is no longer listed as unanswered.

Comment: @Jonathan, site engine prevents accepting own answers in less than 2 days after posting question.

Comment: Ah. Well, then you should accept it after then, assuming that no one else provides a better answer, but I don't know how they could, given how straightforward it is.

Comment: Sure I will, once Stack Overflow will allow me :)